# overloading "new" operator

Tags: c++, new-operator

While I was defining the working of an overloaded new operator declared in a class,
I came across following confusion....

1. HERE ,the return type of the function is 'void',yet I
   have to introduce a return statement.....otherwise my program crashes....why so?
2. What is meant by "void *p"

   ```
   void *myclass::operator new(size_t size)
   {
   void *p;
   p=malloc(size);
   cout<<"IN overloaded new";
   if(!p)
   {
     bad_alloc ba;
     throw ba;
    }  
   return p;
   }
   ```

   to the point clarifications are appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The return type of the function is not void, its a void* (void pointer).  A void pointer is a generic pointer which can point to anything, but it cannot be dereferenced - you have to cast it to another type prior to dereferencing it.

If you don't return the void *, then you're not returning the pointer to the memory you allocated, and the users code will fail.

Comment: Very true :) dontcha just love undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

`void*` is an untyped pointer. It's a pointer that can point to anything. Note that the return type of this function is not `void` but `void*`. It's supposed to return a pointer to the memory that was allocated.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple demonstration of overloaded new

```
void* operator new(size_t num)
{
 return malloc(num);
 }
```

The return type of the overloaded new must be void*. It is expected to return a pointer to the beginning of the block of memory allocated.ie Here it is returning void * and not void(which means doesnt return anything) .